# Backbone.Backgrid infinite loop when calling model.save() on collection change event

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, infinite-loop, put, backgrid

Backbone.Backgrid enters a PUT request loop when I save a changed model inside my collection. The loop only happens when I return the updated (or old) model in the PUT request, but not when returning only a 200 response.

Here is my event code that listens to Backgrid updates and triggers a save for that row:

```
AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend(
    # ...

    initialize: ->
        @items = new Stock.Collections.Items() # collection with URL: /api/items

        @items.on 'change', (item) ->
            console.log 'collection changed'
            console.log(item)
            item.save() # this seems to be triggering additional change events
            return
    # ...
```

Why is my view collection looping on save and how do I prevent it from going bananas?

Comment: **item.save** is indeed triggering change events, but only if you have changed the model's attributes meanwhile. Is it possible that you have an older version of Backbone, because the Changelog lists your problem, but for a version as old as 2010?

Comment: @svetoslavnedkov I'm running Backbone.js 0.9.10, the latest version to-date.

Answer (score 2):

After reading through the Backbone and Backgrid sources, I solved this by setting the `silent` option in my collection changed `save()` call, to precent the propagating `model.set()` calls from raising a loop of change events:

```
item.save null,
    silent: true # important!
    success: (model, res) ->
        console.log('model saved:')
        console.log(model)
    error: (model, res) ->
        console.log('error saving:')
        console.log(model)
```

Comment: I came across this post when hunting down a multiple POST loop and the problem was of course the events firing from multiple (old) copies of the view in question. Just in case it helps anyone else.